# getting compiler used at run-time

Tags: c++, qt

I have written a benchmark and test it with different compilers (MinGW, Visual, 32-bit and 64-bit and want to print out the type of compiler used with the benchmark data.

I have found QSysInfo::buildCpuArchitecture() to get info wether 32-bit or 64-bit build has been performed.

How can I get the info about the compiler name or vendor?

Comment: Such info is not typically stored in compiled executables, and certainly not exposed  y most cross-platform libraries. You would have to gleem such info manually, such as by looking at compiler-specific defines, etc

Comment: Many compilers have `#define` or *macros* identifying the compiler name and version.  However, this is not consistent across all compilers, so you'll have to do research on available macros for each compiler.  You may be able to research using programs that are multi-platform and look at their source code.

Comment: Thanks for posting!
I did it that way, even it is restricted to my case.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
// get compiler used
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#   define CPL "VC++"
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
#   define CPL "Mingw"
#else
#   define CPL "other CPL"
#endif

inline QString compilerInfo() { return( QString(CPL) + " " + (( QSysInfo::buildCpuArchitecture() == "i386")? "32-bit":"64-bit")); }
```

Comment: Note that VC++ is not the only compiler that defines `_MSC_VER`